# Is this an example of a wrapper function?

Tags: design-patterns, python, terminology

I'm working on an application in python.  One of the functions we have is called

```
def createThread(user, status, title, ...):
    # some code here
    system.db.runUpdateQuery("INSERT INTO table(value,...,value) VALUES(%i,...%i)"%(user,status,title,...))
```

The gist is simple - takes parameters and runs an insert on them into a hardcoded table.

Now I have functions like this

```
def createThreadForInvoice(user,...):
    title = "invoice"
    status = "low"
    app.createThread(user, title, status,...)
```

Where the createThreadForInvoice's only function is to preset and edit a few parameters and then pass them onto the createThread function.

Is this a wrapper function or a composite function?  We have this for a bunch of different items like `createThreadForObjectX`.  Are they all wrappers/composites of the `createThread` function?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is (merely) a [wrapper function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function), a function whose main purpose is to call a second function with little or no additional computation.

A [composite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) would be something like `f(g(x))`, where the output of g is passed to f for additional computations, where f and g both provide some computational value beyond simply passing through arguments.